# Signalr Calls are quite large with longPolling transport type - Performance impact

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am using SignalR - transport type longPolling. I am able to see the functionality working as expected. In realtime, I could see there are quite large number of signalR calls which is affecting performance heavily.

It seems, based on my analysis, longPolling creates connection and use it and close it. Then again the connection will be created on demand. I feel, this could be the cause of seeing lot of signalR calls at some point in time.

Could you please share your thoughts on this to resolve / avoid large number of SignalR calls?

When I tried to use foreverFrame as transport type, SignalR connection is not getting enabled. I could see the following error in console.

SignalR: Failed to connect using forever frame source, it timed out after 3000s
SignalR: Stopping forever frame
SignalR: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization
Issue occurred when starting the Signalr Hub.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be default behavior for long polling based on the docs -  Long polling does not create a persistent connection, but instead polls the server with a request that stays open until the server responds, at which point the connection closes, and a new connection is requested immediately. This may introduce some latency while the connection resets.

Your use of foreverFrame may not work because the transport is not available in the browser you are using.

I have yet to understand why anyone would force the transport to a specific one. Possibly, I have just not run into that scenario where it is required.

SignalR will handle the aspect of determining which transport to use with each client, which is one of it's great benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there any way to avoid those polling calls from signalr/poll?transport=longPolling....?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there any way to avoid those polling calls from signalr/poll?transport=longPolling....?
so that my server will not hit those many requests.

you mean, we dont need to explicitly mention transport type using the below snippet

$.connection.hub.start({ transport: "longPolling" })?

OR

$.connection.hub.start({ transport: "foreverFrame"})

if we want the signalR to determine the transport type by its own then do we need to remove the above setting / do we need to set as auto or none? could you please share your thoughts?

Comment: any of the latest version of signalR version would help to avoid lot of signalR/poll?transport=longpolling.... call hits the server for every 2 min interval?  I am using SignalR1.1.2 version currently.

Comment: Your use of foreverFrame may not work because the transport is not available in the browser you are using.   ===> I am using IE 11, isn't foreverFrame transport available in IE browser?

Comment: I would recommend updating to the latest if you can. I am not saying that updating will create any better performance for you as I believe the issue is related to how long polling works. If the conditions (server and client) support Web Socket I think you will notice a much improved performance. To allow SignalR to negotiate the transport just don't specify one: connection.start();

Comment: I tried to enable websockets in Server 2012 for my web application by the following steps.

1. Enabled websocket protocol in IIS
2. Updated httpruntime and compilation entries in web.config as targetFramework="4.5"

Still, the signalR call are not negotiating with websocket transport instead it is still with foreverFrame and longpolling.

any other settings required to enable websocket transport type in web application? 

FYI - I am using signalr 1.1.2 version